# freeing memory from Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-memory

I want to know what happens to the variables/objects that exist inside a fragment after it is destroyed. For example the FloatingActionButton its a instance that leaves inside fragment. When the fragment gets destroyed does the FloatingActionButton also? or do i need to free the memory myself? Also, the finish method on destroyed, do i need to call it?

```
public class Hello extends Fragment {

private final Fragment fragment = this;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


    });
    super.onStart();
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("ButtonScan","Destroyed");
    try {
        finalize();
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: NO . JVM automatically handles the unreachable Objects. And calling `finalize()` does not free any memory, `finalize();` will called by the GC just before freeing the Object.

Comment: @ADM is right - Here is some reading about memory management in Android: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview